# Создание триггера для представления

Tags: sql, sql-server, триггер

Доброго времени суток !

Подскажите как правильно создать триггер для представления на обновление.

То есть, представление отображает данные, и если они меняются по определенному условию, то нужно чтобы срабатывал триггер. Так как доступны триггеры только insted of, то нужно чтобы и само обновление происходило и триггер срабатывал со своим кодом.

Comment: Это невозможно. Триггер может быть на запись в view. но не на выборку из него. А изменение любых данных в БД отлавливается триггерами на таблицах

Comment: Что в данном случае подразумевается под изменением данных в представлении? Что следующий SELECT вернул не то же самое что предыдущий?

Comment: Нет. То есть, представление - это некий запрос, и если допустим данные в таблице поменялись и запрос возвращает другое значение, и вот триггер на это дело..